# What replace the function keybd_event in Virtual TreeView to change the position on the last letter?

Tags: delphi, treeview, virtual

Forgive me for my very poor english but i just want to replace the function (keybd_event) of another function. I want use something better than "keybd_event" (maybe "SelStart" is better option).
Look at my code:

```
procedure TForm1.VirtualStringTree1ColumnClick(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree;
  Column: TColumnIndex; Shift: TShiftState);
var
  Wsk: PVirtualNode;
  Kol: Integer;
begin
  Wsk := VirtualStringTree1.FocusedNode;
  Kol := VirtualStringTree1.FocusedColumn;

  if Assigned(Wsk) then
  begin
    VirtualStringTree1.EditNode(Wsk, Kol);

    keybd_event(VK_RIGHT, 0, 0, 0);
    keybd_event(VK_RIGHT, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
  end;
end;
```

Keybd effect is:

[image]

This function "keybd_event" works fine but maybe do you know other, better function (SelStart for example)?
One man said "you can use SelStart" but VirtualStringTree1 dont have this property but he said "but you can add this property to this" but he will not tell me anything more. So i dont know what to do to get (add) "SelStart" to this. Any ideas?